# Connection to SQL Server 2008 R2 isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried to test if my application is connected to the local database. I don't get any errors, so couldn't quite figure out why it's not working. I only get "no connection" output. I tried to debug it but get connection = null. I have SQL Server 2008 R2 (mixed authentication) and Visual Studio 2008 sp1. I tried connecting using both Windows and SQL Server authentication however neither worked.

This is my `web.config` file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConn" 
         connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }
    protected void btnTestDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Sample; Integrated Security=SSPI");
            connection.Open();
            if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
                Response.Write("Connection OK!");
                connection.Close();
            } else {
                Response.Write("No Connection!");
            }
        } catch {
            Response.Write("No Connection!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working is a bit useless. Instead try to change your exception catch with a meaningful error message like `catch(Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message);}` then report the exact error message

Comment: Also the logic of your if is wrong. If you have a connection open then you don't print "No Connection"

Comment: i am not getting any errors that's what the problem is. not really able to get any exception.

Comment: ok i get this exception: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Answer (score 2):

```
 //Try this
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString());

protected void btnTestDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try {
       con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Response.Write("Connection Open");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Connection Closed");
        }
        con.Close();
    } catch {
        Response.Write("No Connection!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use these namespace... using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;

Comment: If you are using "SQL Server authentication" instead of "Integrated Security=True;" just pass "uid=zzz" and "password=zzz" in webconfig..

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code that tries to open the connection.

When you try to call connection.Open, the result is an exception if you have problems or simply a connection with its ConnectionState=Open.
Your code instead gives the "Connection OK" message if the ConnectionState is closed, but of course, having just called Open, and if you don't have problems, then the ConnectionState is open.

You could try this code....

```
protected void btnTestDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = TestConnection();
    Response.Write(result);
}
private string TestConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...."))
        {
             connection.Open();
             return "Connection opened correctly";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error opening the connection:" + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error as before which is Error opening the connection:Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: This error message means that the ConnectionString is wrong but I can't see any error in that string. (Assuming of course that you have a Sql Server installed on your local machine and with a database Sample)

Comment: By the way, note that in the config file the connection string is wrong: local should be between parenthesys. However the code sample don't use that string in the file config so I have no idea why do you get this error

Comment: i tried connectionstring in differnt way still didn't work: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConn" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sample;User ID=sa;Password=hello123"
     />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: If you have installed SQL Server Express then try with `Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True` and pay attention if the error message changes

Comment: thnks a lot. it finally worked. i also tried to use ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Out of curiosity.What was the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The written `ado.net` code will open the connection for sure, but I doubt the connection string will do. Choose appropriate `connectionstring` from [this dedicated site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).